# Persist CommonsMultipartFile to database

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I am trying to persist a uploaded file to database using JPA. The most "natural" way (to me) is to define domain object as:

```
@Entity
class UploadFile {
  ...
  public CommonsMultipartFile getFileData()
  {
    return fileData;
  }
}
```

But this won't work since there is not such a database mapping type. Searching online, I found that people seems to adapt one of the two methods:

- Define the field as `java.sql.blob;`
- Define the field as `byte[]`

In the `@Controller` class, the incoming `HttpServletRequest` gets cast to `MultipartHttpServletRequest` in order to access the `MultipartFile` and convert it back to `byte[]` stream.

However, with this scheme, I have "random" results which puzzles me: from time to time, I ran into "bean property not readable" error, possible mismatch of return type of getter method on the byte[] field. I double and triple checked my Bean definition, and couldn't find anything wrong.

I guess my questions are two folds: (1) Any idea why this error can happen in this context? (2) more importantly, what are the "recommended" way of handling uploaded file like this?

thanks

Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that either a `java.sql.blob` or a `byte[]` would be the most appropriate way to store an uploaded file in a database.

You should not store a `MultipartFile` or a `CommonsMultipartFile` in a database because these are intended to be temporary objects. Note this from the `MultipartFile` javadoc:

> The file contents are either stored in memory or temporarily on disk.
>   In either case, the user is responsible for copying file contents to a
>   session-level or persistent store as and if desired. The temporary storages
>   will be cleared at the end of request processing.

I don't quite follow what you're doing with your `HttpServletRequest` but it doesn't sound like the easiest way to handle the upload. The easiest way to handle an upload is to make the `MultipartFile` a parameter on your controller method (if you're using Spring 3.0 or later, I think):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void exampleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();

            // Persist those bytes using JPA here

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Exception handling here
        }
    }
}
```

This should work reliably because you've extracted the bytes into your `byte[]` array before the request has finished — and thus before the any temporary files used to handle the upload have been deleted.

Comment: thanks for your reply. A quick question though: say I am using `<form: form>` in JSP to display upload form, and using `modelAttribute` to bound form object to `UpLoadFile`, `path` field is set to `fileData`. So it should be `@RequestParam('fileData')`? will this cause the type mismatch problem?

Comment: I just checked, it did cause the type mismatch problem.

Comment: If you're using a model attribute with a file upload, then you can (should, I think) put the `MultipartFile` in your form (model) object instead of using it as a method parameter. So your controller method would be `exampleFileUpload(@ModelAttribute('fileData') UpLoadFile model)`, your `UpLoadFile` form object would contain a property `MultipartFile file;` and you would access the file via the form object, ie `model.getFile().getBytes();`.

Comment: I finally got it working. As a closure note, the key is not to use <form:input> to define input file, Spring will complain mismatch type, unless additional Binder is place to aid it.