# Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [java.sql.Blob]

Tags: spring

when i used without validation the deatails successfully inserted into DB,But when i applied validation using spring above exception occurr.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]
to required type [java.sql.Blob] for property 'employee_Uploadphoto'
```

could anybody please rectify this one?

Comment: Try to insert `CommonsMultipartFile.getBytes()` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Persist CommonsMultipartFile to database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228859/persist-commonsmultipartfile-to-database)

Comment: I tried It It Doesn't work.........same error occur